# I sent ETH to my receiving contract address

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, cpp-ethereum

I sent ETH to one of my receiving address which is contract address. But this receiving contract address was my personal trading wallet address. But, no transaction I'd has been received. When will I get transaction id and said ETH?

Receiving address: 0x0397070137FC164d467F4b17dcAE0986d5dd5890

Comment: How did you send it? Over which network (mainnet, testnet)?

Comment: I just sent. Don't know whether it was mainnet or testnest.

Comment: Please help me. I am so worried now. I have lost all my earning.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what and how you did it? There's no possible way for us to help if we don't know what is this about.

Comment: I am from India. Zebpay and Unocoin are two leading Crypto exchanges in my country. I have sent from my Zebpay Wallet/account to my Unocoin wallet/account.

Comment: @PranjalHandique You have to ask to Zebpay and/or UnoCoin support. There's nothing else you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your receiving address hasn't received any Ether https://etherscan.io/address/0x0397070137FC164d467F4b17dcAE0986d5dd5890

Comment: Yes. But. I have sent. Is it possible to share images of sending ETH, then I can share or upload as an attachment. But, here no options.

Comment: I searched the Rinkby, Ropsten, Kovan and mainnet and the address hash doesn't exist. It looks as though you may have lost your ether unfortunately as you sent it a non existent address. When you send Ether to an address that "doesn't exist", it means really that no one has the private key for it and cannot use the Ether that gets sent to it. for example https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 has $6.25 million dollars of Ether in it likely from accidental transactions, no one has the private key for it, so that Ether will remain locked up forever

Comment: Now, what to do for recover my ETH? Receiving address is my private wallet address.

Comment: Where private key will be available. If I get private key, then can I able to receover my ETH?

Comment: If you can find the person with the private key then sure, but I have no idea how you would. How much Ether did you lose?

Comment: I have sent 0.89 Ethereum.

Comment: I have found my private key. How to recover my ETH now?